# Angular - Loop through array of objects and convert each object as an array for sending via http request

Tags: angular

Below is my loop

```
    for (let i = 0; i < customAttributes.length; i++){
          if(customAttributes[i].action === 'add') {
            return this.httpc.post(url, customAttributes[i], {headers: httpOptions.headers})
            .pipe(map(res => res));
          }
    }
```

Here `customAttributes` is an array of objects. So, I need to pass each object as an array through http post call for the backend to understand. Here when I say `customAttributes[i]`, it is an individual object, not an array. How can convert it to an array to be sent in the post call. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you must send an array and not an object?

Comment: Yes, the API design is supporting the request body in the form of array, not object.

Comment: have u tried [customAttributes[i]] inside http.post?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to make an array of object's values, you can just do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < customAttributes.length; i++){
    if(customAttributes[i].action === 'add') {
        const attributes = Object.values(customAttributes[i]);
        return this.httpc.post(url, attributes, {headers: httpOptions.headers})
        .pipe(map(res => res));
    }
}
```

But I don't know how are your objects structured, i.e. if they're just a one-level key-value pairs, or you have nested objects and/or arrays as values.